# Problema com checkbox de categorias e subcategoria para exibir seus respectivos produtos

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html5, json

Estou com um problema com jquery, na verdade não tenho muita pratica com jquery, porem trabalho com ajax e json para consulta no banco e retorno de dados.

Bom eu tenho uma pagina que o cliente quer que eu pegue de exemplo: https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/materiais-educativos/ , ao lado esquerdo temos os filtros, Formato, Categoria e Nivel de aprendizado, a cada checkbox que clicamos exibo o material da sua respectiva categoria, até ai tudo bem estou fazendo um  ajax para validação e retorno json e exibo no jquery os materiais que tem o id da categoria retornada via json.

O problema é as categorias pai não consigo retornar todos os materiais filhos e quando desmarco o checkebox, não consigo retornar todos os resultados, sei que sou péssimo para explicar mais de qualquer forma segue o código.
Desconsiderem o php são apenas classes que utilizo para fazer o CRUD
HTML:

```
<!--- filtros -- >
<div class="filtro-materiais">
                    <p class="categoria">Por Formato</p>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="video">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="22" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Video</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="e-book">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="666" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">E-book</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="webinar">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="667" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Webinar</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="kit">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="668" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Kit</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="ferramenta">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="669" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Ferramenta</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                            <p class="categoria">Por categoria</p>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="1015" rel="all">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Atrair</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                        <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1015" name="e" value="1026" rel="cat" id="1015">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Blog</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1015" name="e" value="1027" rel="cat" id="1015">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Links Patrocinados</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1015" name="e" value="1028" rel="cat" id="1015">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Produção de conteúdo</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                        <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="1029" rel="all">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Converter</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                        <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1029" name="e" value="1030" rel="cat" id="1029">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Otimização (A/B Tests)</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1029" name="e" value="1031" rel="cat" id="1029">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Páginas de Conversão (Landing Pages)</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                        <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="1032" rel="all">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Relacionar</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                        <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1032" name="e" value="1033" rel="cat" id="1032">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">CRM e Vendas</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1032" name="e" value="1034" rel="cat" id="1032">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Email Marketing</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1032" name="e" value="1035" rel="cat" id="1032">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Facebook</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                </div>

<!--- fim filtros -- >

<! --- Materiais --->

<div class="col-md-8 material-container">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mat 667 1026">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="destaque"></div>
                                <figure class="capa">
                                    <img title="Webinar RS Submit" alt="Baixe Webinar RS Submit" src="http://localhost:8080/clikss/uploads/800/2017/10/webinar-rs-submit.jpg">
                                </figure>
                                </a><p class="nome-material"><a href="#">
                                    </a><a href="" title="Baixe Webinar RS Submit"> Webinar RS Submit</a>
                                </p>

                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mat 666 1027">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="destaque"></div>
                                <figure class="capa">
                                    <img title="E-book marketing digital" alt="Baixe E-book marketing digital" src="http://localhost:8080/clikss/uploads/800/2017/10/e-book-marketing-digital.png">
                                </figure>
                                </a><p class="nome-material"><a href="#">
                                    </a><a href="" title="Baixe E-book marketing digital"> E-book marketing digital</a>
                                </p>

                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mat 666 1027">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="destaque"></div>
                                <figure class="capa">
                                    <img title="Como fazer campanhas no facebook" alt="Baixe Como fazer campanhas no facebook" src="http://localhost:8080/clikss/uploads/800/2017/10/como-fazer-campanhas-no-facebook.png">
                                </figure>
                                </a><p class="nome-material"><a href="#">
                                    </a><a href="" title="Baixe Como fazer campanhas no facebook"> Como fazer campanhas no facebook</a>
                                </p>

                        </div>
                                    </div>

<! --- fim Materiais --->
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#filters :checkbox").click(function () {
        var action = $(this).attr('rel');
        var cat_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
            data: {action: action, cat_id: cat_id},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("div.mat").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

o Exemplo que temos que seguir seria esse https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/materiais-educativos/

De acordo com o código artual o que eu deveria fazer para conseguir o resultado igual do exemplo?.

Obrigado a todos fico a disposição para tentar explicar melhor.

Comment: Boa tarde, como é uma dúvida de JavaScript, seria melhor você colocar o código HTML gerado pelo PHP. Para facilitar o entendimento do código.

Comment: ok obrigado, eu atualizei o codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a sua lógica do Ajax, eu incluir no post do ajax todos os IDs clicados, separados por virgula (",").
O exemplo a seguir não irá funcionar pois não temos a página PHP funcionando. Se você criar a página "ajax.php", deverá funcionar.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#filters :checkbox").click(function () {
        var action = $(this).attr('rel');
        var cat_id = null;
        $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
          if(cat_id!=null) 
            cat_id +=  ","
          cat_id +=  $(this).val()
        });
        
        
        // O Ajax será enviado com as categorias selecionadas
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/ajax.php',
            data: {action: action, cat_id: cat_id},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("div.mat").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- filtros -->
<form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
<div id="filters" class="filtro-materiais">
                    <p class="categoria">Por Formato</p>
                    <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="video">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="22" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Video</span>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="e-book">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="666" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">E-book</span>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="webinar">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="667" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Webinar</span>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="kit">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="668" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Kit</span>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                <label class="form-check-label" id="ferramenta">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="669" rel="catformat">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Ferramenta</span>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                                            <p class="categoria">Por categoria</p>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="1015" rel="all">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Atrair</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                        <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1015" name="e" value="1026" rel="cat" id="1015">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Blog</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1015" name="e" value="1027" rel="cat" id="1015">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Links Patrocinados</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1015" name="e" value="1028" rel="cat" id="1015">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Produção de conteúdo</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                        <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="1029" rel="all">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Converter</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                        <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1029" name="e" value="1030" rel="cat" id="1029">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Otimização (A/B Tests)</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1029" name="e" value="1031" rel="cat" id="1029">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Páginas de Conversão (Landing Pages)</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                        <div class="form-check">
                            <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="e" value="1032" rel="all">
                                    <span class="nome-filtro">Relacionar</span>
                                </label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                                                        <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1032" name="e" value="1033" rel="cat" id="1032">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">CRM e Vendas</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1032" name="e" value="1034" rel="cat" id="1032">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Email Marketing</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-left: 30px;" class="form-check">
                                    <form method="POST" action="" name="formCat">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input all 1032" name="e" value="1035" rel="cat" id="1032">
                                            <span class="nome-filtro">Facebook</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                                </div>

<!--- fim filtros -- >

<! --- Materiais --->

<div class="col-md-8 material-container">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mat 667 1026">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="destaque"></div>
                                <figure class="capa">
                                    <img title="Webinar RS Submit" alt="Baixe Webinar RS Submit" src="http://localhost:8080/clikss/uploads/800/2017/10/webinar-rs-submit.jpg">
                                </figure>
                                </a><p class="nome-material"><a href="#">
                                    </a><a href="" title="Baixe Webinar RS Submit"> Webinar RS Submit</a>
                                </p>

                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mat 666 1027">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="destaque"></div>
                                <figure class="capa">
                                    <img title="E-book marketing digital" alt="Baixe E-book marketing digital" src="http://localhost:8080/clikss/uploads/800/2017/10/e-book-marketing-digital.png">
                                </figure>
                                </a><p class="nome-material"><a href="#">
                                    </a><a href="" title="Baixe E-book marketing digital"> E-book marketing digital</a>
                                </p>

                        </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mat 666 1027">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="destaque"></div>
                                <figure class="capa">
                                    <img title="Como fazer campanhas no facebook" alt="Baixe Como fazer campanhas no facebook" src="http://localhost:8080/clikss/uploads/800/2017/10/como-fazer-campanhas-no-facebook.png">
                                </figure>
                                </a><p class="nome-material"><a href="#">
                                    </a><a href="" title="Baixe Como fazer campanhas no facebook"> Como fazer campanhas no facebook</a>
                                </p>

                        </div>
                                    </div>

<!-- fim Materiais -->
</form>
```

Outra forma de fazer seria filtrando os elementos a partir dos elementos já carregados em memória, igual no exemplo que você enviou. Mas seria uma estrutura totalmente diferente.